# She has to be somewhere else later

Tags: phrases

This is the situation:
Ann is going to meet Fred at 6pm. She will give him something and then she has to go because she has another meeting somewhere else at 7.

Could you please give me some tips for sentences which can be used when I want to tell Fred why to be on time?

Something like
"Please be there on time. It's important because Ann ..." 
(She has to be somewhere else later/then/after? She has something to do? She has to go?) <- I know it's wrong.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What makes you think you can't use "she has to be somewhere else later (right after meeting you)"?

Comment: I would say "It's important because Ann has to be somewhere else afterwards".  You could put "immediately" before "afterwards" to emphasise the importance of not delaying her.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - Actually, "later" is more idiomatic than "afterwards", though it might be misunderstood if the person hearing the phrase is not fluent in idiomatic English.

Comment: @HotLicks perhaps - I would say that meeting one is at 6, and then she has to get to another meeting at 7, there's perhaps not much of a gap between the meetings, especially if she has to travel between them.  If that's the case, then I think "afterwards" is a better choice than "later"  - later could be 10 o'clock or something, but "afterwards" gets the message across that if you're late for the first meeting you're going to mess her schedule up.

Answer (score 1):

You could say something like, "Please arrive punctually as Anne has another appointment scheduled soon after the meeting and needs to accommodate for travel time."